# Access an Array in Backbone Model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

[image]

Hi all,

How do I access the fields(Employees & Location) of each object in this array in Backbone?

```
var DataModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    // urlRoot: "https://corporate-dashboard.firebaseio.com/locations.json"
    urlRoot: ""
});

var locationModel = new DataModel();
locationModel.urlRoot = "https://corporate-dashboard.firebaseio.com/locations.json"
locationModel.fetch()



console.log(locationModel.get("Location")); >> Got "undefined"
tried locationModel.get(0) and locationModel[0] >> got "undefined"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you can get a [Backbone Collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection) of models out from you endpoint. Than you can access to all the models.

[Collection Models](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-models): Raw access to the JavaScript array of models inside of the collection. Usually you'll want to use `get`, `at`, or the [Underscore methods](http://underscorejs.org/) to access model objects, but occasionally a direct reference to the array is desired:

```js
var DataCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    url: 'https://corporate-dashboard.firebaseio.com/locations.json'
});

var locationCollection = new DataCollection();
locationCollection.once('sync', function(r) {
    console.log('Collection length: ', r.length);
    console.log(r.models[0]);
    console.log(r.models[0].get('Employees'));
    console.log(r.models[0].get('Location'));
});
locationCollection.fetch();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Works perfect. But how do I bind it to a view? Thanks.

Comment: You can create a Backbone View and pass the collection: `var view = new MyView({collection: new DataCollection()}); `. In the `MyView` you declare the `sync` event,  make the `fetch` and manipulate the collection to be displayed in your view template